# check if a string contains a letter does not work as expected

Tags: xml, xslt

I want the below code to return the classes I mentioned in the code. Oxygen does not show any errors. However, both times the `<xsl:otherwise>` runs.

```
<xsl:template match="tei:pb">
    <xsl:element name="div">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains('@n', 'v')">
                <xsl:attribute name="class">
                    <xsl:text>pbStyle left;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:text>[Fo</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="@n"/>
                <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:attribute name="class">
                    <xsl:text>pbStyle right;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:text>[Fo </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="@n"/>
                <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>                    
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
```

I also tried putting the `<xsl:element name="div>` inside the `<xsl:when>` and in the `<xsl:otherwise>` accordingly.To no avail. 
I fear that it is due to the `'@n'`, which cannot be processed as a string.

If I change the line in question to

```
<xsl:when test="contains('value-of select=@n', 'v')">
```

All elements return

```
        <xsl:attribute name="class">
            <xsl:text>pbStyle left;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
```

Can anyone hint me at what I'm missing? 
(I have a bootstrap carousel set up dynamically with about 400 elements, which are styled according to these classes)
All the best, 
Thanks

Comment: Well, `contains('@n', 'v')` checks whether the string literal `@n`, i.e. the string with the two characters `@` and `n` contains the character `v`. If you want to check whether an attribute named `n` contains the letter `v` you need `contains(@n, 'v')`.

Comment: it would help if you post a sample the XML you are trying to match

Comment: and of course the desired output you are trying to achieve would be good to have also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution reduces (in XSLT 3.0) to

```
<xsl:template match="tei:pb">
  <div class="pbStyle {if (contains(@n, 'v')) then 'left' else 'right'};">[Fo {@n}]</div>
</xsl:template>
```

XSLT is often said to be verbose, but it doesn't have to be.

Comment: Kind of what I was thinking as well as the OP solution was not DRY at all, and that semi-colon the OP has seems odd here

Comment: I'm just learning xslt. :-) So any improvements are welcome! Which semi-colon do you mean? that inside the ´<xsl:text> </xsl:text>´ at the end? I guess I don't need that. mix up from css. but it doesn't break the code :-D DRYing it up makes only sense, once I have a working version, at least for me :-) Thanks to all of you!

Comment: As I cannot edit any more: 
One minor thing: the part ´[Fo {@n}]´ that you, Michael Kay, provided fails to transform to the number I need. Thus I am using ´<xsl:value-of select="@n"/>´ for now.

Comment: I was assuming an XSLT 3.0 processor and the setting expand-text="yes".

Answer (score 0):

Hi and I have an answer that I want to share with you. 
Feel free to add a better one, if you know some!

```
 <xsl:template match="tei:pb">
     <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="contains(string(@n), 'v')">
                <xsl:element name="div">
                <xsl:attribute name="class">
                    <xsl:text>pbStyle left;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:text>[Fo </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="@n"/>
                <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
         <xsl:when test="contains(string(@n), 'r')">
                <xsl:element name="div">
                <xsl:attribute name="class">
                    <xsl:text>pbStyle right;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:text>[Fo </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="@n"/>
                <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
                </xsl:element>                    
            </xsl:when>
     </xsl:choose>
```

Of course, I have to set the type of `@n`to be a string.